# SQL Returning a sum and a single value from a table on a condition

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains the product, warehouse number (numbered 1-8), quantity-on-hand, and list-price for inventory items.  Each line contains specific data for a particular warehouse.  We have 8 warehouses in total, so each product has 8 lines associated with it in the table.

I need to return the product, the sum of the quantity-on-hand for all 8 warehouses, but only want to show the unique list-price for a selected warehouse.  I can use the sum aggregate function with a group-by to return the correct summation of the quantity-on-hand, but can't figure out how display the unique list-price for one particular warehouse within the same query.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you showed us sample data from your table, along with the output you expect.  Have you tried something yet yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You never showed us your schema, but I can suggest the following query.  The key point here is that you should be summing the quantity on hand for a given produce across warehouses in a subquery, and not in the main outer query.  Then, join this subquery to the outer query to use the sum of quantity on hand per product.

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.quantity_sum
FROM products p1
(
    SELECT product, SUM(quantity_on_hand) AS quantity_sum
    FROM products
    GROUP BY product
) p2
    ON p1.product = p2.product
WHERE p2.warehouse_num = 3     -- or whatever warehouse you want to use
```